# I have fetched my RSS feed data with jQuery.rss.js, now how to put this result in slider?

Tags: php, jquery, html, xml, rss

I have my website surffares.com/blog, the blog is created in WordPress and rest of the website is created with PHP, so I wanted to show the blogs updates on my websites home page, which is surffares.com.

So I fetched all the RSS feed, with jquery.rss.js, the code is given below-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      <title>jquery.rss example</title>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-rss/3.3.0/jquery.rss.js"></script>
      <script>
         jQuery(function($) {
           $("#rss-feeds").rss("https://www.surffares.com/blog/feed/",
           {
             entryTemplate:'<li><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a><br/>{teaserImage}{shortBodyPlain}</li>'
           })
         })
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="rss-feeds"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

This code fetching the RSS feed of my website blog and show it in list form. so, I want to add this result, into the slider, one by one, two sliders at a time, so how can it be done, with jquery? I have been trying other plugins also, but none of them works for me.

Comment: jQuery 1.6 is *ancient*, the whole 1.x (and 2.x!) branch of jQuery is unsupported and doesn't get security updates any more. Upgrade to a supported version of jQuery.

Comment: okay, but right now rss can be customized with it right?